# Fuse resistor type

Tags: resistors, switch-mode-power-supply, fuses, flyback

I want to build a flyback SMPS based on "TNY274". About the fuse before bridge, I don't know what kind of resistor should I use for correct operation!

**Metal oxide film** or **Metal film** or **Thick and thin film** or **Carbon film**?

The calculated resistor is **8.2 \$ \Omega \$ /1W**.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What has the resistor got to do with the fuse?

Comment: The resistor before bridge, acts as a fuse

Comment: resistors are not designed to be used as fuses

Comment: So, what is RF1 supposed to do? Control inrush current?

Comment: @Icy - you should look up "fusible resistor"

Comment: @WillDean- fair enough. I think you have just answered OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component you're looking for is called a 'fusible resistor'.  It's a resistor which is designed to fail in a predictable way.  You won't have any trouble finding them now you know what they're called.

Comment: Which is hinted at in the schematic by the notation "RF" :-)